# How to make Dropdownlist faster?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, drop-down-menu, visual-studio-2017

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlICode" runat="server" 
     CssClass="form-control m-t-5 js-example-tags js-example-placeholder-single" 
     AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
```

I have 35000 records in table of database, I am fetching `id` and `name` columns from table ,but due to 35000 records to which my dropownlist is getting very slow (I am fetching record using a stored procedure).

I try to use a DataSource control, use caching but didn't work well.

Comment: I'd argue that a dropdown with more than 20 options is not user friendly anyway. Have you looked into something [like this](https://www.google.com/search?q=asp%3ADropDownList+with+search)?

Comment: Yes this dropdownlist givings search option but still its sometimes get slow or show page not responding.

Comment: You need to provide more information. How and when are you loading from the DB? How does your query look like? How is the result data bound to the control?

Comment: Please feel free to let know if you have any question.

Comment: Hello, you can classify your data, or use paging, which can greatly reduce the data read at one time.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out, a dropdown is good for about 100 choices tops. You load more then that then not only does page load time zoom up, you are simple making life difficult for your users.

Worse yet, think of JUST 10 users on your site. if they all navigate to that page, you just pulled 350,000 records of data!!! (and not done anything of much use expect place a rather high load on the database server.

So, any time a dropdown reaches about 100-150 choices, you have to change this approach.

You also don't mention if there is a "benefit" to additional filtering on that selection.

9 out 10 times? Performance is achieved by *better design.*

This is also why often we see say a c# application run faster then vb.net. They both actualy use the "same" .net system, and c# does not run faster then vb.net. However, with better design approaches, then better application performance is achieved. (very rare say that throwing more hardware, more CPU, and more memory will fix such issues).

Now, there are "boatloads" of cool fill out while you type examples floating around for asp.net and a combo box.

However, they all near suffer from two whopping big in your face issues.

First up, they still tend to FIRST download the WHOLE list of selections, and then let you "select as you type". This of course defeats the whole purpose of good perforamnce, since you still downloading the WHOLE list.

Bottom line:

Loading the whole list has to be taken off our table of "viable" choices.

Next issue:

While SOME examples even do use some "very" nice ajax calls, don't download the  "whole" list of choices, but actually "hits" the database as you type?

Ok, "fantastic" many of these examples are, but they leave out the WHOPPER in the room.

That whopper?

Well, for anything more then 50 choices, I am willing to bet 9 out 10 times, we need a PK value from the database! In other words, user sees, searches, uses, enjoyes typing in some text value, but we NEED that all imporant datbase PK id. (you know, the concept and glue that has held togehter our whole industry for 50+ years!!!).

So, most (if not all) examples I can find of "cool + nice" as you type + search examples leave out this VERY important second part (that 2nd part is the need for using and having the PK database id value).

So, lets cook up an example here.

Say we need to select a city. However, that could be near any city, and a city table is going to have about 130,000 rows.

So, when Google, or Microsoft interviews you?

They ask a lot of quesitons of the "how far", "how big" type of questions. The reason of course is what is the "scale" of the problem at hand.

You can easy walk down the street to the corner store in less then 5 minutes. However, what about a trip to some big grocery store? That might be 10 miles away, and that is half a day of walking. Again, NOT practical to walk to that store 10 miles away everyday, but 5 minutes down the street is a viable choice.

So, we have a choice and table of 130,000 rows of a city.

What do we do?

We can't fill that combo box with 150,000 rows, can we?

So, the answer is in "most" cases to change the UI.

So, in place of a combo box (drop down list), we could do this:

[image]

If you look close, in above we ONLY pulled a
total of 191 records out of 155,955

so, that's going to be fast!

Now, we COULD I suppose hook up a "type" into the City column.

and I suppose if we only started the search say after 3 characters or more, then we probably could hook up a ajax call, and not even say pop the above UI.

So, I am temped to try this, and see how well it works.

If you think that building a whole "UI" like above is too much, then I could post some JavaScript + a web method, and we hit the main City table directly, and see how fast/well this performs.

However, if you can "narrow" down the criteria, then often you wind up with not only "amazing" performance (page load time is instant), but in most cases the result is a better UI for the user anyway.